# Getting data from multiple cursors in Android ListView

Tags: android, sql, android-cursor

In my project I have two cursors. One is handling all books records form one table and another is join on two tables holding rents records and users data. I am using two cursors because join on all was showing only books that were rented, and not all. Just what I've figured out - if you join and one of column is empty then it will be omited in resulting cursor.

The proble is that I want to have it all in one `ListView`. For now I've created custom `CursorLoader` because all data loading is done via `Loader`. My custom loader is returning the list of cursors based on the list of elements - this is the only difference.

In my `CursorAdapter` implementation I want to set text of `TextView` to rent or free based on values from second cursor.

Unfortunately you can't do something like: `secondCursor.moveTo(bookId)` because book Id can be way bigger than size of secondCursor so it will just throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also I've been testing `CursorJoiner`:

```
    CursorJoiner joiner = new CursorJoiner(data.get(0)/*first cursor*/, 
new String[]{Tables.BOOK_ID}, data.get(1)/*second cursor*/, new String[]{Tables.RENT_COLUMN_BOOK_ID});
            int i = 0;
            while(joiner.hasNext()){
                CursorJoiner.Result result = joiner.next();
                i++;
                switch(result){
                case BOTH:
                    DebugLog.i("Both: " + i);
                case LEFT:
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
```

The problem is that it isn't working as Iwould expect - the i value is changed accordingly to first cursor. Even after switching in `CursorJoiner` constructor cursors order.

For short time I've been also thinking about using [ExtednedCursor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/61414c2c4627ab588cc0f54eae5e0c5591f7d8d9/src/com/android/contacts/calllog/ExtendedCursor.java) but the value in added column is always this same, so it is useless.

My question is - do you know any idea how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. I guess I should have started from this. I've been using `INNER JOIN` which is creating new table containing only values that are in both tables. Instead I should have use `OUTER JOIN` which is joining all records no matter what.